# Ignore some fields for JSONB Deserialization in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring JPA Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
public class Project implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private long id;


  @Column(name = "version_id")
  private Long version;

  @Column(name = "created_by")
  private String createdBy;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_by")
  private String updatedBy;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

  @Column(name = "is_archived")
  private Boolean archived;

  private String commentsRoomId;

  private String workflowType;
  private String workflowId;

  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private Map<String, ProjectSection> sections;
```

Now the data in the last property is a JSONB Property which should ignore some of the fields. as it wouldnt be present in the DB either.

Now when I try to get the data I get the following error.

```
The given Json object value: {s06=ProjectSection(version=1, enabled=true, type=milestones, values={}, visibility=null, sectionId=null, sectionSchema=null)
```

which says this after the json repr.

Now my Section looks like

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ProjectSection {

  @JsonProperty("version_id")
  private Long version;

  @JsonProperty("enabled")
  private Boolean enabled;

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;

  @JsonProperty("values")
  private Map<String, ProjectField> values;

  @JsonProperty("visibility")
  private List<String> visibility;

  // Not Srtored in DB
  @JsonIgnore
  @Transient
  private String sectionId;

  @JsonIgnore
  @Transient
  private ProjectTemplate.SectionSchema sectionSchema;
```

I think maybe because of it being in a JSONB Nested fields the `transient` doesn't make sense.
How should I make sure these values are ignored when its deserialising from the DB and loads properly.
If I remove these extra fields, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some mappers ModelMapper or DozerMapper to handle such cases.

Comment: I don’t really need to map it to any dto. I’m getting this on the read itself when I’m getting from DB

Comment: I understand but the mapper layer would be beneficial from any layer to any layer. Sometime you may need to exclude more more columns. You cannot keep on change your annotation always. Better go for mapper which works in all the cases.

Comment: I agree that a mapper is better solution and I would like to add that you should look into Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views which even improves the performance as it goes all the way down to the query level and only fetches what really is necessary: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage

Comment: I disagree with the use of a mapper unless absolutely necessary. Your classes represent your entities. The annotations can be used to determine how they must be represented in persistence, when passed on as DTOs and the classes can even contain business and validation logic. Having an anemic domain model with logic dispersed through the rest of the code and requiring everything in triplicate just feels counterproductive. It gets tiresome very fast, it becomes much easier to create bugs and it adds yet more moving parts that can fail.

Comment: @G_H Can you please help me with the best practice and an example to understand what you are trying to convey. may be a code snipper as answer would be easy to review and accept it.